# using getidentity in azure mobile app: easy api

Tags: api, azure, mobile

I am using following code to get user details in azure mobile services. I am trying to migrate to azure mobile app, and get user details in easy api. how to do that ?

```
getIdentity({
        success: function (identities) {
        var req = require('request');
        if (identities.facebook) {
            var fbAccessToken = identities.facebook.accessToken;
            var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' + fbAccessToken;
            req(url, function (err, resp, body) {
                if (err || resp.statusCode !== 200) {
                    console.error('Error sending data to FB Graph API: ', err);
                   // req.respond(statusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, body);
                } else {
                    try {
                        var userData = JSON.parse(body);

                        console.log(JSON.parse(userData));
                        res.json(userData);
                        //item.UserName = userData.name;
                       // request.execute();
                    } catch (ex) {
                        console.error('Error parsing response from FB Graph API: ', ex);
                       // request.respond(statusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, ex);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Same problem, and didn't find any info on microsoft documentation about that. Maybe is not possible yet?

Answer (score 1):

Following [this example](https://ahoycoders.com/2015/07/09/xamarin-forms-social-authentication-with-azure-mobile-services-part-3/), I edited the script and it works for me with google authentication.

```
    currentUser.getIdentity()
    .then((data) => 
    {        
        var http = require('request');
        var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo' +
            '?access_token=' + data.google.access_token;

        var reqParams = { 
            uri: url, headers: { Accept: 'application/json' } };
        http.get(reqParams, function (err, resp, body) {
            var userData = JSON.parse(body);             
            res.status(200).send( {message: userData});
        });

    }, console.error);
```

Comment: Which controller do you do this in? Is this part of a custom controller? Sorry, I'm new to Azure Apps!

Comment: This is a node.js code and should be added as an API in your azure mobile service. It's explained here [here](https://ahoycoders.com/2015/07/09/xamarin-forms-social-authentication-with-azure-mobile-services-part-3/)

Comment: for those wondering : var currentUser = req.azureMobile.user;

Answer (score 0):

This link advises using the context to request for additional user details in an EasyTable Node.js script instead of an EasyAPI. Only resource I could find that doesn't rely on the classic Azure portal.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#Debugging

Edit: the above code didn't work for me, so maybe this will help anyone else out

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is a build in function already. below code is invoking .auth/me action on your client and returns you claims object. claims object is a dictionary of information, you selected on azure portal.

```
 public async Task<AppServiceIdentity> GetIdentityAsync()
    {
        if (Client.CurrentUser == null || Client.CurrentUser?.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Not Authenticated");
        }

        if (identities == null)
        {
            identities = await Client.InvokeApiAsync<List<AppServiceIdentity>>("/.auth/me");
        }

        if (identities.Count > 0)
            return identities[0];
        return null;
    }

    public class AppServiceIdentity
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id_token")]
    public string IdToken { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "provider_name")]
    public string ProviderName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "user_id")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "user_claims")]
    public List<UserClaim> UserClaims { get; set; }
}

public class UserClaim
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "typ")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "val")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

So you will get the info from claims object like this for name

```
 var name = identity.UserClaims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type.Equals("name")).Value;
```